# Is there a way to get the Math.min() for random integers? Java

Tags: java, math, random, int

I am currently making a game and I'm trying to compare the shortest path that is displayed on screen (which is a random generated path of integers) and the path that the user takes. This part of the code is the one in which I try to get the `Math.min()` of the total paths on screen:

```
int path1 = randomNum3 + randomNum8;
int path2 = randomNum2 + randomNum7;
int path3 = randomNum + randomNum6;
int path4 = randomNum3 + randomNum5 + randomNum7;
int path5 = randomNum2 + randomNum5 + randomNum8;
int path6 = randomNum + randomNum4 + randomNum7;
int path7 = randomNum2 + randomNum4 + randomNum6;


int caminoMasCorto = Math.min(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5,
        path6, path7);
```

The error that is showing me is this one:

> no suitable method found for min(int,int,int,int,int,int,int)
>
> method Math.min(int,int) is not applicable
>
> (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. As the error says, `Math.min(int, int)` takes **two** arguments. Change

```
int caminoMasCorto = Math.min(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5,
        path6, path7);
```

to

```
int caminoMasCorto = Math.min(path1, Math.min(path2, 
        Math.min(path3, Math.min(path4, Math.min(path5, Math.min(path6, path7))))));
```

**or** (as Andreas noted)

```
int caminoMasCorto = Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(
        path1, path2), path3), path4), path5), path6), path7);
```

Alternatively, you would write your own `min` function that takes an arbitrary number of `int`(s) and returns the smallest. Like,

```
private static int myMin(int... vals) {
    if (vals == null || vals.length < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No values");
    }
    int t = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
        t = Math.min(t, vals[i]);
    }
    return t;
}
```

And then use

```
int caminoMasCorto = myMin(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5,
        path6, path7);
```

Use whichever you find most readable.

Comment: I think this looks better: `Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(Math.min(path1, path2), path3), path4), path5), path6), path7);`

Comment: @Andreas Readability is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 4):

To find the minimum of a lot of `int` variables, use:

```
int caminoMasCorto = IntStream.of(path1, path2, path3, path4, path5,
        path6, path7).min().getAsInt();
```

If you're not using Java 8+, you can do this:

```
int caminoMasCorto = path1;
for (int value : new int[] { path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7 })
    caminoMasCorto = Math.min(caminoMasCorto, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Java's `Math.min` accepts two arguments. To extend this to multiple numbers, try this method:

```
public int minExtension (int... numbers) {
    int minimum = numbers[0];

    for (int number : numbers) {
        minimum = Math.min(number, minimum)
    }

    return minimum
}
```

Call it like this

```
int caminoMasCorto = minExtension (path1, path2, path3, path4, path5, path6, path7);
```